# tablet / desktop media query override my mobile first CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

I come here to ask a question I've begin yesterday a project so I currently do a prototype of my design 
I've begin my CSS in mobile first but when I using my media query, the mobile first property get override and take the tablet query as my main css and i don't understand why :/

here is the html

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="mysect1">
        <h2> Presentation </h2> 
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="mysect2">
        <h2> Produits </h2> 
        <img src="./assets/images/fauteuil.png">
        <img src="./assets/images/tensio.png">
        <img src="./assets/images/inco.png">
        <img src="./assets/images/lit.png">
    </section>
```

and here my CSS

```
  #mysect1 p {
        font-size:1.1em;
      }


    #mysect2{
      text-align:center;
    }

    #mysect2 img {
      width:90%;
    }


    @media (min-width:768px) {



      #mysect1 p {
        font-size:1.8em;
      }



      #mysect2 {
        text-align:center;
      }

      #mysect2 img {
        width:70%;
      }
}
```

thanks !

Comment: Share your media query for tablet and mobile.

Comment: Provide working example somewhere please because we really cannot understand what are you trying to achieve and where is the problem. If the problem is that the `@media (min-width:768px)` overrides your css while on desktop "mode" just change `min` to `max`.

Comment: hm no the problem is that my query already override my mobile CSS

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a separate media query for mobile

```
@media (min-width:480px) {  
  #mysect1 p {
    font-size:1.1em;
  }
  #mysect2{
    text-align:center;
  }
  #mysect2 img {
    width:90%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried but that not working he's still override by the tablet query

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is my @media(min-width:768px) override my phone query when i'm on phone emulator ( on google dev)

here is my complet HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> BLCM Tunisie </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="logo"><img src="./assets/images/bastide.jpg"></div>
        <div id="op-horizontalnav">
            <ul class="op-sectionlist">
                <li class="op-v-item"><a class="op-v-link" href="#mysect1">PRESENTATION</a></li>
                <li class="op-v-item"><a class="op-v-link" href="#mysect2">PRODUITS</a></li>
                <li class="op-v-item"><a class="op-v-link" href="#mysect3">EQUIPE</a></li>
                <li class="op-v-item"><a class="op-v-link" href="#mysect4">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </header> 
    <div id="container">
        <section id="mysect1">
            <h2> Presentation </h2> 
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="mysect2">
            <h2> Produits </h2> 
            <img src="./assets/images/fauteuil.png">
            <img src="./assets/images/tensio.png">
            <img src="./assets/images/inco.png">
            <img src="./assets/images/lit.png">
        </section>

        <section id="mysect3">
        <h2> Equipe </h2>
        <div id="imageTeam">
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerome Yvanez <br/> Developper</p> </div> 
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jean bon <br/> Web marketer</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jesui Palas <br/> CM</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Sylla Bique <br/> Graphiste </p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Mac Donald <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="./assets/images/jerome.jpg"><p> Jerry Golay <br/> Developper</p> </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section id="mysect4">
            <h2> Nous contacter </h2>
            <form action="post">
                <input placeholder=" Nom et Prénom" type="text" id="firstname">
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email">
                <input type="text"size="6" id="contactContent" placeholder ="contenue du message">
                <input type="submit" id="send"/>
            </form>
        </section>

    </div>

    <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and here my complet CSS

```
 html, body {
  border: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica LT Condensed;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none; 
  width:100%;
}

body{
    background: url(../images/fond.png);
    background-size: 200%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 60%;
    background-position-y: 118%;
}

section {
  padding:20px;
}

h2, h3 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:4em;
}


#container{
  margin-top:150px;
}

/*============ CSS 'Header' mobile first ========== */



header.active #logo img {
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  margin:4px 0 0 20px;
  padding-left:40px;
}

#logo { text-align:left; }

#logo img{
  width:140px;
  height:55px;
  transition:  .4s all linear;
  -moz-transition:  .4s all linear;
  -webkit-transition: .4s all linear;
  -o-transition:  .4s all;
  margin:14px 0 0 20px;
  display:block;
}

header{
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:right;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:501;
  height:80px;
}

#navbar { 
  text-align:right;
  position:relative;
  font-size:19px;
}

ul { margin-top:-34px; }

li{ 
  display:inline; 
  margin-top:;
  padding-right:50px;  
  transition: .4s all linear;
  -moz-transition: .4s all linear;
  -webkit-transition: .4s all linear;
  -o-transition: .4s all linear;
}


.active li{ 
  font-size:0.8em; 
  padding-top:20px, 
  padding-right:40px; 
}

.active ul { margin-top:-30px; } 

a.active {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

a{ text-decoration: none; color:white;}




@media(min-width: 480px){
  /* =========== CSS 'Presentation' mobile first =========== */


  #mysect1 p {
    font-size:1.1em;
  }



  /* =========== CSS 'Produits' ============= */ 

  #mysect2{
    text-align:center;
  }

  #mysect2 img {
    width:90%;
  }


  /* ========== CSS 'Equipe' mobile-first ===========*/
  #imageTeam { 
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top:20px; 
    order:2;
  }

  .imgWrapper { display:inline-block; width: 42%; }

  .imgWrapper p { 
    background-color:red; 
    padding:20px 117px 21px 110px; 
    color:white; 
    margin-top:-5px; 
    width:inherit;
    font-size:39px;
    display:inline-block;
  }

  #imageTeam img{ width:100%;

  }
  /*=========== CSS 'Contact' mobile first ============= */ 

  form {
    width:100%;
  }

  input, textarea, select {
    font-size:44px;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:none;
    outline:none;
    resize:none;
    border:0;
    transition:all .3s;
    border-bottom:1px solid #F7941D;
    border-right:1px solid #F7941D;
    width:100%;

  }

  input:focus { border-bottom:3px solid #F7941D; border-right:3px solid #F7941D;}

  #send {     
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #F7941D;
    margin-bottom: -6px; }

  #send:hover{ background-color:#B40303; }

  #contactContent { height:100px; }

  #mysect4 {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0px;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }
}


/*============== DEBUT CSS TABLETTE ============= */ 


@media (min-width:768px) {

/*============== CSS 'Presentation' TABLETTE =============*/

  #mysect1 p {
    font-size:1.8em;
  }

/*============= CSS 'Produits' TABLETTE =================*/ 

  #mysect2 {
    text-align:center;
  } 

  #mysect2 img {
    width:70%;
  }

  .imgWrapper {
    width:35%;
  }

  #imageTeam img {
    width: 86%;
  }

  #imageTeam p {
    padding:10px 85px 12px 84px;
    font-size: 21px;

  }
}
```

[this is a pics of what I tell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqEVO.png)